# Cannot add foreign key constraint error occurs when I try to add a THIRD Foreign Key to my table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, create-table

I have been trying to add the attribute **O_BagelID** into my `Order` Table, however whenever I attempt to add it in, I get the error "Cannot add foreign key constraint".

As you can see I've made sure that both the foreign key in Order, and the reference in Bagel are of the same type. When I remove **O_BagelID** and all the associated fields, I no longer get that error.

```
CREATE TABLE `Order`(
    OrderID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    O_CustomerID INTEGER NOT NULL,  
    O_BagelCardID VARCHAR(16),
    O_BagelID INTEGER,  
    Order_date DATE NOT NULL, 
    Order_Cost DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    Discount_applied BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(OrderID,O_CustomerID,O_BagelCardID,O_BagelID),

    FOREIGN KEY (O_CustomerID) 
    REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY (O_BagelCardID) 
    REFERENCES BagelCard(BagelCardID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY (O_BagelID) 
    REFERENCES Bagel(BagelID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE  
);

CREATE TABLE Bagel(
    BagelID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Contains_Nuts BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    Price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL, 
    Description VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(BagelID)
);
```

Comment: Add the error message

Comment: "Cannot add foreign key constraint." That is all I get.

Comment: create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create table `Bagel` first and then create table `Order`. When you create REFERENCES to another table it should be already exist:

```
CREATE TABLE Bagel(
    BagelID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Contains_Nuts BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    Price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL, 
    Description VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(BagelID)
);

CREATE TABLE `Order`(
    OrderID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    O_CustomerID INTEGER NOT NULL,  
    O_BagelCardID VARCHAR(16),
    O_BagelID INTEGER,  
    Order_date DATE NOT NULL, 
    Order_Cost DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    Discount_applied BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(OrderID,O_CustomerID,O_BagelCardID,O_BagelID),

    FOREIGN KEY (O_CustomerID) 
    REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY (O_BagelCardID) 
    REFERENCES BagelCard(BagelCardID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY (O_BagelID) 
    REFERENCES Bagel(BagelID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE  
);
```